# Jersey REST service as a proxy

Tags: java, rest, proxy, jersey, jersey-2.0

I need to build a REST API (Jersey 2) that should act as a proxy to an external service for certain calls (all the urls with a certain path in it). I need to get some statistics out of those calls (number of invocations), so in addition to proxy the calls I need to have some small logic for all of them.

What would the best way to achieve this in jersey? I am not familiar with the Jersey framework, so I'll appreciate if anybody can point me to the right direction!

Thanks!
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Metrics library. It works with Jersey and can get you a bunch of data points.
http://metrics.codahale.com/

Comment: Thanks we are going to use that. The problem is mainly related to finding the best way to use a REST Jersey service as a proxy to an external REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) (from Netflix) within Jersey to achieve this. It provides very nice stats. Check this [dashboard](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Dashboard) provided by Hystrix.

[image]